# Unable to replace placeholder {0} in ErrorMessage of a RegularExpressionAttribute

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

```
[StringLength(100),
 RegularExpression(RegexPatterns.NoBracketsRegEx,
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources),
    ErrorMessage = "HTML tags are not allowed in {0} field")]
public virtual string Title { get; set; }
```

When I try to enter Html tags in Title field I am getting the error message:

> "HTML tags are not allowed in {0} field"

instead of

> "HTML tags are not allowed in Title field".

I am using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0`

I have tried setting `Display(Name="Title")` but still no luck!! Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [`ErrorMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessage.aspx) and [`ErrorMessageResourceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcetype.aspx) together. Their use is mutually exclusive.

For **non-localized** error messages, you can use the [`ErrorMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessage.aspx) property initialized with a string literal (without format specifiers because, like you've discovered, they will be shown as is).

For **localized** error messages, use the [`ErrorMessageResourceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcetype.aspx) property together with the [`ErrorMessageResourceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcename.aspx) property.

Here's are a couple of related blog posts that may help:
 [Localizing Validation Using DataAnnotations](http://publicityson.blogspot.com/2010/07/localizing-validation-using.html), and
 [ASP.NET MVC 2: Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).